# Upper limit on the number of pause commands in a frame

Tags: beamer, debugging, pause

Is there any upper limit on the number of pause commands in a frame in beamer, when it is used along with the `\only<>{}` command ?. I have a simple beamer example with 14 pause commands, but the last four pauses do not generate extra slides at all ! They all appear in the same slide ! Can anyone please help. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[blue,aspectratio=1610]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Decoding Stabilizer codes}
\only<1>{
1

\vspace{0.3cm}

}%
\pause
% 2 slide
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.6\textwidth}
\only<2-10>{2-10 L}

\vspace{0.3cm}

\only<3-4>{3-4 L}
\only<5>{5 L}
\only<6>{6 L}
\only<7>{7 L}
\only<8>{8 L}
\only<9,10>{9-10 L}
\only<5-10>{5-10 L}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.45\textwidth}
\only<2-10>{
2-10 R 2
\vspace{0.3cm}

%
\pause
% 3 slide
2-10 R 3

\vspace{0.3cm}

%
\pause
% 4 slide
2-10 R 4

\vspace{0.3cm}

%
\pause
% 5 slide -- contents in the left column
%
\pause
% 6 slide
2-10 R 6

\vspace{0.3cm}

%
\pause
% 7 slide
2-10 R 7
%
\pause
% 8 slide
2-10 R 8
%
\pause
% 9 slide
2-10 R 9
}
\end{column}
\end{columns}

\vspace{0.5cm}

%
\pause
% 10 slide
\only<10>{
10

\vspace{0.3cm}

}%
\pause
% 11 slide
11

\vspace{0.3cm}

%
\pause
% 12 slide
12

\vspace{0.3cm}

%
\pause
% 13 slide
13

\vspace{0.3cm}

%
\pause
% 14 slide
14
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you replace \only with \visible, the problem will go away.

Comment: The problem here is that the pause counter is reset when you leave the `columns` environment, so it doesn't generate the expected overlays. A workaround is to use `\pause[10]` for the first `\pause` after the environment (which is in l. 74, after the `\vspace`) so the counter is set to the correct value.

Comment: @diabonas: Your comment can be turned into an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that the `pause` counter is reset when you leave the `columns` environment, so it doesn't generate the expected overlays. A workaround is to use `\pause[10]` for the first `\pause` after the environment so the counter is set to the correct value (cf. [the beamer manual, section 9.1](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf#subsection.9.1)):

```
\documentclass[blue,aspectratio=1610]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Decoding Stabilizer codes}
\only<1>{
1

\vspace{0.3cm}

}%
\pause
% 2 slide
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.6\textwidth}
\only<2-10>{2-10 L}

\vspace{0.3cm}

\only<3-4>{3-4 L}
\only<5>{5 L}
\only<6>{6 L}
\only<7>{7 L}
\only<8>{8 L}
\only<9,10>{9-10 L}
\only<5-10>{5-10 L}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.45\textwidth}
\only<2-10>{
2-10 R 2
\vspace{0.3cm}

%
\pause
% 3 slide
2-10 R 3

\vspace{0.3cm}

%
\pause
% 4 slide
2-10 R 4

\vspace{0.3cm}

%
\pause
% 5 slide -- contents in the left column
%
\pause
% 6 slide
2-10 R 6

\vspace{0.3cm}

%
\pause
% 7 slide
2-10 R 7
%
\pause
% 8 slide
2-10 R 8
%
\pause
% 9 slide
2-10 R 9
}
\end{column}
\end{columns}

\vspace{0.5cm}

%
\pause[10]
% 10 slide
\only<10>{
10

\vspace{0.3cm}

}%
\pause
% 11 slide
11

\vspace{0.3cm}

%
\pause
% 12 slide
12

\vspace{0.3cm}

%
\pause
% 13 slide
13

\vspace{0.3cm}

%
\pause
% 14 slide
14
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```